# Django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model %s that has not been installed

Tags: python, django

I'm getting up this message when I execute manage.py makemigrations.
using django 2.1 and python 3.7

I was looking for similar questions and answer but, I didn't make it.

Im doing customize user model django2.

here is my project tree and files.

## project tree

- prj_testing_mimi

  - accounts <-- added app

    - MimiUser.py <-- added here
    - MimiUserManage.py <-- added here
    - ...
  - dashboard
  - landing
  - prj_testing_mimi

    - setting.py
    - ...

### setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for prj_testing_mimi project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '$k!#-sj=bxfg)twq3660#pdmcg8%l4k(rlimvj(*h@2y&%_64v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'dashboard',
    'accounts',
    'landing'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'prj_testing_mimi.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], 
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'prj_testing_mimi.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja-JP'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.MimiUser'
```

### MimiUser.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from accounts.MimiUserManager import MimiUserManager


class MimiUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    class docstring
    """
    email = models.EmailField(_('email_address'), unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first_name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last_name'), max_length=150, blank=True)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(_('staff_status'), default=False, help_text=_('staff admin site.'))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=True, help_text=_('active help text'))
    latest_login = models.DateTimeField(_('latest_login'), default=timezone.now)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date_joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = MimiUserManager()
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        function docstring
        :return:
        """
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name).strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """
        function docstring
        :return:
        """
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        function docstring
        :param subject:
        :param message:
        :param from_email:
        :param kwargs:
        :return:
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

### MimiUserManager.py

```
"""
docstring
"""
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class MimiUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    class docstring
    """
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        function docstring
        :param email:
        :param password:
        :param extra_fields:
        :return:
        """

        if not email:
            raise ValueError("email 未入力")
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must have is_staff=True')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('superuser must have is_superuser=True')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

### Error Messages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 178, in get_model
    return self.models[model_name.lower()]
KeyError: 'mimiuser'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 165, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 210, in get_model
    return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 181, in get_model
    "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
LookupError: App 'accounts' doesn't have a 'MimiUser' model.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\prj_testing_mimi\manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\prj_testing_mimi\manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_c
ommand_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_module
s
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 20, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "D:\mimi\workspace\env_testing_mimi\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 170, in get_user_model
    "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'accounts.MimiUser' that has not been installed
```

Comment: Your `MimiUser` model should be in `accounts/models.py` instead of `accounts/MimiUser.py`. If you really want to define it in `MimiUser.py`, then add `from .MimiUser import MimiUser` to `accounds/models.py`.

Answer (score 0):

`MimiUser` should be a class into `accounts/models.py`.

You do not have to define `get_full_name`, `get_short_name` and `email_user`, you are inheriting it from `AbstractUser`.